# How can I properly loop through MongoDB entries with Redux, Express and React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

I am building a logging system with React, Redux, Express, Mongo and Node and I am trying to get my logs from the server but keep running into this error:

**Failed prop type: Invalid prop `log` of type `object` supplied to `Logs`, expected `string`.**

Logs.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import LogItem from './LogItem';
import Preloader from '../layout/Preloader';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getLogs } from '../../actions/logActions';

const Logs = ({ log: { logs, loading }, getLogs }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getLogs();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  if (loading || logs === null) {
    return <Preloader />;
  }

  return (
    <ul className='collection with-header'>
      <li className='collection-header'>
        <h3 className='center'>Maintenance Logs</h3>
      </li>
      {!loading && logs.length === 0 ? (
        <p className='center'>No logs to show...</p>
      ) : (
        Object.keys(logs).map((log) => <LogItem log={log} key={log._id} />)
      )}
    </ul>
  );
};

Logs.propTypes = {
  log: PropTypes.string,
  getLogs: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  log: state.log,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getLogs })(Logs);
```

logActions.js

```
//Get logs from server
export const getLogs = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    setLoading();

    const res = await fetch('/api/logs');
    const data = await res.json();

    dispatch({
      type: GET_LOGS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGS_ERROR,
      payload: error,
    });
  }
};
```

Logs.js
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');  const LogSchema = mongoose.Schema({   message: {     type: String,   },   attention: {     type: String,   },   tech: {     type: String,   },   date: {     type: Date,     default: Date.now,   }, });  module.exports = mongoose.model('log', LogSchema);`

It's causing my logs not to render. I know the database is an Object oriented database, so I used `Object.keys(logs).map((log) => <LogItem log={log} key={log._id} />)` in the main Log component but nothing is rendering. Any help would help, thank you.

Comment: The immediate error is that you're passing an object to a prop that's defined as a string, just like the error says. We can't see the shape of your data, though, so we don't have a way to fix it.

Comment: Since you do this `logs.length === 0` i assume the logs is an array although you treat it as an Object `Object.keys(logs)...` Why? Anyways try to change this `Object.keys(logs).map((log) => <LogItem log={lo...` to this `logs.forEach((log) => <LogItem log={log...` you can also try `console.log(logs)` to see what is the value of logs.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. My log schema is as follows: 

Log.js
`const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const LogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  message: {
    type: String,
  },
  attention: {
    type: String,
  },
  tech: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('log', LogSchema);
`
Should I just change the required proptype to an object?

Comment: I used Object.keys since I was getting **logs.map is not a function**. I changed it to `logs.forEach` and am getting **logs.forEach is not a function**. When I `console.log(logs)` I get null and the object itself.